# WebBrowser Fails with MP3 URL

Tags: wpf, vb.net, browser

My application has a webbrowser control that works fine with most sites, but is having trouble with pages intended to play MP3s.

The code below sends the URLs to webViewer, my WebBrowser control. Regular pages work, however, one like [this](http://www.goaztech.com//media/01sandbox/satellite-ace/podcast.mp3) does not, and results in the browser displaying a white page with the "x" shown in the image at the top left. The page does load properly in Internet Explorer and displays a QuickTime player that plays the file.

```
Private Sub NavigateTo(ByVal webAddress As String)
    Try
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(webAddress.Trim()) Then
            MsgBox("This link is under construction...")
            Return
        Else
            If webAddress.Contains("http://") = False Then webAddress = "http://" & webAddress
            Dim navPage As New Uri(webAddress)
            webViewer.Source = navPage
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("The URL for this button is invalid. Please contact AzTech IT for help.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Satellite Tablet Application")
        ErrorHandler.Helpers.LogMessage(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Is there a workaround for this issue?

[image: What the browser displays when navigating to the URL]

Comment: Have you checked the mime type that is setup for the .mp3 extension on your web server? What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: The file is hosted by a third party - would I have to contact them to find out this information or is there another way?